# Proving claim on the minimization of a residual over a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

Suppose $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is a positive, semidefinite matrix and $b \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ with $\hat{x}$ being the exact solution to $Ax = b$.

> Let $e = x - \hat{x}$, $r = b - Ax$, and $\|y\|_{A} := (Ay,y)^{\frac{1}{2}}$.
>
> Prove that if $x$ minimizes $\|e\|_{A}$ over some subspace $X$, then it also minimizes $\|r\|_{A^{-1}}$ and the quantity $\xi(x) = \frac{1}{2}(Ax,x) - (x,b)$ over the same $X$.

I feel that there is some assumption missing here, but I approached it as trying to rearrange $\|e\|_{A}$ to get an equivalent expression as to the ones desired without much luck. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will use the substitution $A\hat{x}=b$ freely. Now $||e||_A=\sqrt{e^TAe}$. Since $A$ is psd. $||e||_A>0$ for all $e$. Thus minimizing $||e||_A$ is same as minimizing $||e||_A^2=e^TAe$. Now $$||e||_A^2=(x-\hat{x})^TA(x-\hat{x})=x^TAx-2x^Tb+\hat{x}^Tb$$ Last term is irrelevant and you can scale the equation by $2$ which answers your second part. Now since $A\geq 0$, $||e||_A^2$ is convex. Differentiating and equating it to zero gives $Ax=b$ which implies that $\hat{x}$ is the solution if it belongs to $X$. Or any point in $X$ such that $Ax=b$ is a solution. Now for $||r||_{A^{-1}}$, using similar arguments, you can focus on $||r||_{A^{-1}}^2$. Now, use the substitutions $A^{-1}b=\hat{x}$ and $A\hat{x}=b$. Now after your re-arrange, you will get the same expression.

Comment: Hello. Thank you very much for your nice response. The first part is the portion giving me the most trouble. For clarity, may you add the argument for the first part?

Comment: Since $r=Ae$, $\|r\|_{A^{-1}}=\|e\|_A$. So no more work to prove the same for this quantity.

Comment: Of course it is clear now. Thank you.